# Borel and Hirzebruch's notation relevant to characters of representations of Lie algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

On page 467 of the paper [A. Borel and F. Hirzebruch, Characteristic Classes and Homogeneous Spaces, I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372795?seq=1), the authors discussed a function from the universal covering of a maximal torus of a Lie group to complex numbers, taking the form as in the following picture:

[image: Excerpt from Borel and Hirzebruch - Characteristic classes and homogeneous spaces - I]

which looks somewhat like, but is different from, the usual definition of the character of a representation.

I am missing the context in which this formula makes sense. Are there any proper references that help make the context clearer?

Comment: It is better to type up the content of what you are asking about (which should be easy, since it's a short passage), rather than leaving it as an image.  For example, text in images cannot be searched easily.